# How to increase the height of a "such that" (\mid) symbol in an equation in LyX?

Tags: math-mode, lyx

I am very new to LyX and LaTeX in general. The professor wants us to use Lyx for assignments. So, Word equations, which I am familiar with and could solve this easily, is out of the equation.

Say I have the following equation:

[image]

Here is the code generated by LyX.

```
S=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}1\\
-1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-\nicefrac{3}{5}\\
\nicefrac{2}{5}\\
1
\end{pmatrix}z\mid z\in\mathbb{R}\right\}
```

The `|` ("such as") is represented by `\mid`. Is it possible to make `\mid` grow to the height of brackets containing it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I'm not sure it would look very nice if you have a vertical rule of this size. However you can have  a solution with the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command from `mathtools`, replacing `\mid` with `\,\vert\,`.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you very much. I tried `\,\vert\,` manually and it doesn't seem to autogrow. Maybe it needs to be done with `mathtools`? So, I set `mathtools` to "Load always" in the document. Where do I use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`?

Comment: In  the preamble. I see I've mistyped my comment: it's `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX`  that should be used, and the spacing will be better  with `\:` instead of `\,`.

Comment: Is `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\mid}{\:\vert\:}` right? It did not work and I tried `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\test}{\:\vert\:}` as a test. LyX did not reformat `\test` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've created the large curly braces with `\left\{` and `\right\}`, respectively, you could draw the "given" conditioning bar via `\middle|`. Use `\;` "thickspace" directives around `\middle|`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\begin{document}
\[
S=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix} \sfrac{-3}{5} \\ \sfrac{2}{5} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
z
\;\middle|\;
z\in\mathbb{R}
\right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't seem like LyX recognizes `\middle|` or even `\middle`. I have both `amsmath` and `amssymb` loaded. I updated my question to include the code generated by LyX. It is my understanding that LyX does not let you edit code manually? Maybe this helps? However, I did figure out how to use `pmatrix` instead of `array`. So, thank you!

Comment: @Oliver - I'm afraid I've never used lyx myself. Sorry.

Comment: I believe that you can insert LaTeX directly into LyX's math. LyX might not render it for you, but when you compile to PDF it should look fine.

Comment: @scottkosty is correct, I use this answer all the time. Note that if you want a faster testing loop, you can turn on instant preview and have it render into the final image as soon as you leave the equation environment: https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/InstantPreview